# C++ Checking if a character is not in a string with || not working

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on this game where the player gets asked to play again. I am used to checking if a condition is not met and then return false, so at the end I can simply add return true. This also helps with nesting.

If I do it the other way around it works:

```
bool AskToPlayAgain() {
    cout << "Do you want to play again? ";
    string Response = "";
    getline(cin, Response);

    if (Response[0] == 'y' || Response[0] == 'Y')
    {   
        cout << "True!\n";
        return true;
    }   

    cout << "False!\n";
    return false;
}
```

This will return true on y and Y, and False on every other character.

However. The way I want it is like this:

```
if (Response[0] != 'y' || Response[0] != 'Y')
{   
    cout << "False!\n";
    return false;
}   

cout << "True!\n";
    return true;
```

Only, no matter the response, it will always validate to false. Why is that? And how can I fix it?

Comment: You should learn about [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Wasn't this asked yesterday as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain English, your code is asking:

> If the first character in "Response" is something other than 'y', **or** the first character in "Response" is something other than 'Y', this expression is true.

This statement can never be false.  It's obviously either not 'y' or not 'Y'; it can't be two values simultaneously.  One of the two inequalities will always be true, and the entire expression will therefore also always be true.

What you should be asking is:

> If the first character in "Response" is something other than 'y', **and** the first character in "Response" is also something other than 'Y', this expression is true.

Which, in C++, is expressed as:

```
if(Response[0] != 'y' && Response[0] != 'Y')
```

Answer (score 8):

If you invert the conditions on both sides, you also have to invert the operator. That is to say, `||` becomes `&&` and vice versa. ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

Think about it: `Response[0]` has only one value, so it can't be equal to two values, so it must always be unequal to one of the two.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine `Response[0] == 'y'`, in this case `Response[0] != 'Y'` is `true`. In case when `Response[0] == 'Y'` the condition `Response[0] != 'y'` becomes `true`. So your `Response[0] != 'y' || Response[0] != 'Y'` is always `true`.

Answer (score 1):

### Translating to [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and applying [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

If `Response[0] == 'y'` is , and `Response[0] == 'y'` is ,

---

Then the following:

```
if (Response[0] == 'y' || Response[0] == 'Y')
    {   
        cout << "True!\n";
        return true;
```

can be formally written as (returning `true`)

```
 ∨
```

Truth table:

```
      ∨ 
00      0 (not 'y' or 'Y')
01      1
10      1
11      1
```

---

and the following, (which is not equivalent):

```
if (Response[0] != 'y' || Response[0] != 'Y')
{   
    cout << "False!\n";
    return false;
```

can be formally written as (answer is inverted, returning `false`)

```
¬(¬ ∨ ¬)
```

Truth table (always false in this program):

```
     ¬(¬ ∨ ¬)
00      0 ok,  same as  ∨ 
01      0 not ok, differs from  ∨ 
10      0 not ok, differs from  ∨ 
11      1 ok, but will never happen, Response[0] cannot be both 'y' and 'Y'
```

---

Now, in order to invert the first statement ( `∨` ), De Morgan's rule states that:

```
¬( ∨ ) ⇔ ¬ ∧ ¬
```

or, equivalently:

```
 ∨  ⇔ ¬(¬ ∧ ¬)
```

And so, writing `¬(¬ ∧ ¬)` we get:

```
if (Response[0] != 'y' && Response[0] != 'Y')
{   
    cout << "False!\n";
    return false;
```

Truth table:

```
     ¬(¬ ∧ ¬)
00      0 same as  ∨ 
01      1 same as  ∨ 
10      1 same as  ∨ 
11      1 same as  ∨
```